# mock describe_subnets function boto3

Tags: aws-lambda, mocking, pytest, boto3, botocore

I need help to mock test function on boto3 describe_subnets function.

```
def check_belongsto_describe(list_subnet):
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name='us-east-1')
    ec2_client = ec2.meta.client
    response = ec2_client.describe_subnets(SubnetIds=list_subnet)
    return None
```

but when it run on pytest with:

**monkey patch**

```
def test_check_belongsto_az_monkeypatch(monkeypatch):
    def client_mock(service="ec2", region_name='us-east-1',    
        aws_access_key_id="testing",
        aws_secret_access_key="testing",
        aws_session_token="testing"):
        return MockClientBoto3()

    monkeypatch.setattr(boto3, "client", client_mock)
    list_subnet = ['testid1','testid2']
    az = 'us-east-1'
    response = fw_init.check_belongsto_describe(list_subnet)
    assert response == None
```

or

**mock_ec2**

```
@mock_ec2
def test_check_belongsto_az_mock():
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name='us-east-1',
    aws_access_key_id="testing",
    aws_secret_access_key="testing", 
    aws_session_token="testing")
    ec2_client = ec2.meta.client
    list_subnet = ['test1','test2']
    az = 'us-east-1'
    response = fw_init.check_belongsto_describe(list_subnet)
    assert response == None
```

I got this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeSubnets operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
```

How can mock, stub, test, or pass this function to be able to validate Auth without Failure or management of the control exception?

Comment: Can you show the function your are mocking? You define a function for the monkeypatch, but where do you use it?

Comment: The question needs to be clear and the code provided should at least be reproducible in a minimal attempt. The information provided is to vague.

Comment: Hi @jordanm & Roxy, Just update the code, thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It need was created the VPC and subnet previous to mock the describe_subnets function.

```
@mock_ec2
def test_subnets_boto3():
    ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2", region_name="us-east-1")
    vpc = ec2.create_vpc(CidrBlock="10.0.0.0/16")
    subnet = ec2.create_subnet(VpcId=vpc.id, CidrBlock="10.0.0.0/18")
    list_subnet = [subnet.id]
    az = 'us-east-1'
    response = fw_init.check_belongsto_describe(list_subnet)
    assert response == None
```